# Relay starting on but not going off

Tags: arduino

I write some very basic code to start on the relay and wait for 5 to 3 sec and then turn off it and exit the loop.
relay starting on but its not turning off and also relay taking the same time to start as I set the delay time (delay time = starting time) I don't know why.

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add more information to your question such as how the wiring looks like. Also, the question body is missing the actual question (it's only in the title).
I'd recommend you to read the stackoverflow guide on how to ask a good question. This will make it more likely for you to get good & fast answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your code seems fine but I suggest you use an infinite loop instead of `exit()` function. I think your problem is with the wiring. Also, I suggest you ask your question in https://arduino.stackexchange.com.

Comment: many relay modules activate the coil if signal line is LOW. latching relay modules switch on signal change

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is , loop running continuously with out exit. Which turns ON the relay immediately after OFF. Try code below

```
int count=0;

void setup() 
{ 
pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
 } 

void loop() 
{ 
if(count<1)
{
digitalWrite(7, HIGH); 
delay(3000); 
digitalWrite(7, LOW); 
count++;
}
 }
```

If you are facing the problem again, try swapping HIGH and LOW in above code, 
it is active LOW for some boards.